# (My First App)Android gradle Build with 61 errors ..I dint code anything and simply ran an empty activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

build.gradle:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
  android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.user.myfirstapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

 dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

This is the error in Android Studio:

> ```
>     Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>     Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>     Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>     Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>     Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>     Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>     Error:    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>     Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>     Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>     Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>     Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>     Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>     Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>     Error:    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     Error:    at va.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>     Error:    at va.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>     Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>     Error:    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>     Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>     Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>     Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>     Error:    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
>     Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>     Error:Exception in thread "main" 
>     Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>     Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>     Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>     Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>     Error:    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>     Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>     Error:    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>     Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>     Error:    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
>     Error:    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>     Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>     Error:Exception in thread "main" 
>     :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
>     Error:    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>     Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>     Error:    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
>     Error:Exception in thread "main" 
>     Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>     > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> ```
>
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 1
>           Information:BUILD FAILED
>           Information:Total time: 12.13 secs
>           Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>           Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>           Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>           Error:    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>           Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>           Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>           Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>           Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>           Error:    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>           Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>           Error:    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>           Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>           Error:    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
>           Error:Exception in thread "main" 
>           Information:61 errors
>           Information:0 warnings
>           Information:See complete output in console

Answer (score 0):

Change this in your Gradle

```
 compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
```

Comment: thanks a lot ,,iT WORKED!!,, I have no idea about android code,, but i have a quite strong base in C/C++ langage ,, what should I learn to correct this myself?